# Editing html data table, Data shows up in the wrong area

Tags: php, mysqli

The data form the html table is already showing up in the `editlocator.php` 
but the data are showing up in the wrong area

[image]

**editest.php**

```
    <?php

include('dbconn.php');

$query  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_locators WHERE accholder_ID='1'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Cisu/css/footable.core.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Cisu/css/footable.metro.css">
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
            <script src="/Cisu/javascript/jquery/footable.js"></script>
            <script src="/Cisu/javascript/jquery/footable.paginate.js"></script>  
            <script src="/Cisu/javascript/jquery/footable.filter.js"></script>  
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Cisu/css/search.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Cisu/css/footable.editable-1.0.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        </head>
        <body>


            <div id="header">
                <img src="/Cisu/images/sbma.png" class="logo" id="logo"></img>
                <a style = "float:left;">Account Settings</a>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">Locators</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navigation">
                            <ul class="ul-sidebar">
                    <li class="li-sidebar">
                        <a class="active">View Locators</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            <form class="form-style-1">

            <ul class="ul-sidebar">
            <li class="li-sidebar">    <label class="header-label">Company Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="filter"/></li>
    </select>
            </ul>
            </form>

            </div>
            <div id="section">
                <table class="footable" data-page-size="3" data-filter="#filter" data-filter-minimum="4"  data-first-text="FIRST" data-next-text="NEXT" data-previous-text="PREVIOUS" data-last-text="LAST">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th> 
                    <th>Company Name</th> 
                    <th>Nationality</th> 
                    <th>Primary Address</th> 
                    <th>Industry Code</th>
                    <th>TIN</th> 
                    <th>Status</th> 
                    <th>Employees</th>
                    <th>Account Holder ID</th>
                    <th>EDIT</th> 
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                    <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
                <?php
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;
?>
               <tr>
                    <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_ID'];
?></td>
                    <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_CompanyName'];
?></td>
                    <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_Nationality'];
?></td>
                    <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_PrimaryAddress'];
?></td>
                    <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_IndustryCode'];
?></td>
                    <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_TIN'];
?></td>
                    <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_Status'];
?></td>
                    <td><?php
    echo $row1['locators_Employees'];
?></td>
                    <td><?php
    echo $row1['accholder_ID'];
?></td>
                    <?php
    echo '<td><a href="editlocator.php?locators_ID=' . $row1['locators_ID'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
?>

                </tr>
                <?php
endwhile;
?>

                </tbody>

                <!-- the pagination -->
                <!-- hide-if-no-paging = hide the pagination control -->
                <tfoot class="hide-if-no-paging">
                <td colspan="9">
                    <div class="pagination"></div>
                </td>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">

           $(document).ready(function(){

               $('.footable').footable();

           });

        </script>

            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                S.B.M.A Centralized Information System 
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**editlocator.php**

```
    <?php

include("dbconn.php");

function renderForm($id = '', $accid = '', $companyname = '', $nationality = '', $primaryaddress = '', $industrycode = '', $tin = '', $status = '', $employees = '')
{

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/add.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <Title>
        EDIT
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <img src="images/sbma.png" class="logo" id="logo"></img>
            <a style = "float:left;">Account Settings</a>
            <a href="AdminMenu.php">Home</a>
            <a href="DeptMenu.php">Department</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
                    <form class="form-style-1" action="" method="post">
             <ul>
                <fieldset class="fieldset-company">
                <input type="hidden" name="locators_ID" value="<?php
    echo $id;
?>" />
                <p>ID: <?php
    echo $id;
?></p>
                <input type="hidden" name="accholder_ID" value="<?php
    echo $accid;
?>" />
                <p>Account ID: <?php
    echo $accid;
?></p>            
                    <li>
                        <label>Company Name</label>
                        <input type='text' name='companyname' id='companyname' maxlength="50" value="<?php
    echo $companyname;
?>"/>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <label>Nationality</label>
                        <input type='text' name='nationality' id='nationality' maxlength="50" value="<?php
    echo $nationality;
?>"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Primary Address</label>
                        <input type='text' name='primaryaddress' id='primaryaddress' maxlength="50" value="<?php
    echo $primaryaddress;
?>"/>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <label>Industry Code:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='industrycode' id='industrycode' maxlength="50" value="<?php
    echo $industrycode;
?>"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>TIN:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='tin' id='tin' maxlength="50" value="<?php
    echo $tin;
?>"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Status:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='status' id='status' maxlength="50" value="<?php
    echo $status;
?>"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Employees:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='employees' id='employees' maxlength="50" value="<?php
    echo $employees;
?>"/>
                    </li>
                    </fieldset>

                         <li>
                      <input type='Submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
                         </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="section">


            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
    S.B.M.A Centralized Information System 
    </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
}

// if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
if (isset($_GET['locators_ID'])) {
    // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        // make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
        if (is_numeric($_POST['locators_ID'])) {
            // get variables from the URL/form
            $id             = $_POST['locators_ID'];
            $accid          = $row1['accholder_ID'];
            $companyname    = htmlentities($_POST['locators_CompanyName'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $nationality    = htmlentities($_POST['locators_Nationality'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $primaryaddress = $_POST['locators_PrimaryAddress'];
            $industrycode   = htmlentities($_POST['locators_IndustryCode'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $tin            = htmlentities($_POST['locators_TIN'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $status         = $_POST['locators_Status'];
            $employees      = htmlentities($_POST['locators_Employee'], ENT_QUOTES);


            if ($stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE tbl_locators SET locators_CompanyName = ?, locators_Nationality = ?, locators_PrimaryAddress=?, locators_IndustryCode =?, locators_TIN =?, locators_Status=?, locators_Employee =?
WHERE locators_ID=?")) {
                $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $id, $accid, $companyname, $nationality, $primaryaddress, $industrycode, $tin, $status, $employees);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
            // show an error message if the query has an error
            else {
                echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
            }

            // redirect the user once the form is updated
            header("Location: editest.php");
        }
        // if the 'id' variable is not valid, show an error message
        else {
            echo "ID VARIABLE NOT VALID!";
        }
    }
    // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
    else {
        // make sure the 'id' value is valid
        if (is_numeric($_GET['locators_ID']) && $_GET['locators_ID'] > 0) {
            // get 'id' from URL
            $id = $_GET['locators_ID'];

            // get the recod from the database
            if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_locators WHERE locators_ID=?")) {
                $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
                $stmt->execute();

                $stmt->bind_result($id, $accid, $companyname, $nationality, $primaryaddress, $industrycode, $tin, $status, $employees);
                $stmt->fetch();

                // show the form
                renderForm($id, $accid, $companyname, $nationality, $primaryaddress, $industrycode, $tin, $status, $employees);

                $stmt->close();
            }
            // show an error if the query has an error
            else {
                echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
            }
        }
        // if the 'locators_ID' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the view.php page
        else {
            header("Location: editest.php");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Table Structure**
[image]

Comment: `<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>` remove that semi-colon. That's an end of statement character. As for the rest, you'll need to go through your entire code.

Comment: @ Fred -ii I  removed it and nothing change

Comment: It would be a lot easier to follow if your php had some indenting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug what's being returned from the database.  If it's not what you're expecting, you need to find out what values $stmt->bind_result is assigning to your variables.  Since your query returns all fields, check the structure of your tbl_locators table.

```
$stmt->bind_result($id, $accid, $companyname, $nationality, $primaryaddress, $industrycode, $tin, $status, $employees);
$stmt->fetch();

var_dump($accid);

// show the form
renderForm($id, $accid, $companyname, $nationality, $primaryaddress, $industrycode, $tin, $status, $employees);
```

Comment: it says string(7) "Company"

so its dumping the locators_companyname  value in the $accid ?

Comment: Try matching the order of the variables being set by $stmt->bind_result to the fields as they appear in your table's structure.  That will assign the correct values to your variables.

Comment: I tried that and it works 
the problem now is that 
its not updating